# laravel The configuration file database.php does not exist

Tags: laravel-5

I am working on laravel project but I am stuck due to this message"An Error Was Encountered

The configuration file database.php does not exist."

Answer (score 0):

I solved this after realizing that the project I was working on was merged with codeigniter project and that the file database.php was missing in codeigniter.I created it and that was it.